# Nami wallet API implementation example for web app

Tags: nami-wallet, webapp, reactjs

Are there any examples out there for how to implement Nami wallet end to end for a website (with or without React)? For example, how can I create a button for my site which upon being clicked asks the user if they want to connect their wallet to the site OR if the user has already granted access, then their wallet is opened where they can create a TX, see their TX history, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best resource I am aware of for you to get started integrating with Nami wallet is this repository:

https://github.com/dynamicstrategies/cardano-wallet-connector

The sample (available via a Live demo) shows how integrations work with various wallets.

Several other resources I have found useful in developing my understanding of Wallet Integration and the Cardano Serialization Library (A utility to make working with Cardano data structures easier) are:

- https://github.com/pyropy/full-stack-cardano - Simple next js integration
- https://github.com/dendorferpatrick/nami-wallet-examples/tree/master - A Comprehensive and well-documented breakdown of Nami wallet integration with an applied real-world use case
- https://github.com/tango-crypto/cardano-wallet-js - Superbly documented overview of using the Cardano Serialization Library
- https://github.com/Felippo001/nami-wallet-api - Lightweight integration with Nami and Blockfrost
- https://www.cardano-caniuse.io/ - Site that shows which wallets support various API commands
- https://srdjanstankovic.com/2021/12/24/how-to-sign-and-submit-cardano-cli-transaction-using-nami-wallet.html - Nice blog post on signing transactions

Hope that helps!